# Reducing two views into one?

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon all,

I am new to mySQL. I have everything working just as I want it, but I could only achieve what I wanted by creating a first view, then referencing it in the final view. I wanted to know whether this is bad practice and will result in slower performance or not? And also, just for learning sake whether it could be all done by using a single view. I have tried and tried but keep getting errors.

First I create this view, which I call intermediate view:

```
  CREATE VIEW intermediate_view AS (
  SELECT 
    freight,
    shipping_date,
    receiver,
    tracking_no,
    left(cast(receiver as int), 3) as vendor_id,
    DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) AS days_in_transit,
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) > 5 then "Problem"
    WHEN DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) < 0 then "Not shipped yet"
    ELSE "In transit" 
    END
    AS Status
  FROM tracking
);
```

I'm then creating a final view to join data to it from another another table. My second view is

```
CREATE VIEW final_view AS (
SELECT
    intermediate_view.freight,
    intermediate_view.shipping_date,
    intermediate_view.receiver,
    intermediate_view.tracking_no,
    intermediate_view.days_in_transit,
    intermediate_view.Status,
    vendors.vendor_name
    FROM intermediate_view
    JOIN vendors
    on intermediate_view.vendor_id = vendors.vendor_id
);
```

Basically, all the second table is doing is matching the first 3 numbers of left(cast(receiver as int), 3), to another table table where those 3 numbers have a corresponding company name. Is there a way to join this in one view?

Hopefully I've explained this well enough! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your cast will not work in MySQL, so use this

```
CREATE VIEW final_view AS (
SELECT 
    t.freight,
    t.shipping_date,
    t.receiver,
    t.tracking_no,
    left(cast(t.`receiver` as UNSIGNED), 3) as vendor_id,
    DATEDIFF(now(),t.shipping_date) AS days_in_transit,
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(now(),t.shipping_date) > 5 then "Problem"
    WHEN DATEDIFF(now(),t.shipping_date) < 0 then "Not shipped yet"
    ELSE "In transit" 
    END
    AS 'Status',
    v.vendor_name
  FROM tracking t JOIN
  vendors v
    on left(cast(t.`receiver` as UNSIGNED), 3) = v.vendor_id
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much - worked perfectly. I don't fully understand your code and the cast issue (as it was previously working) but I'll go through it now in detail!

Comment: mys code is simple take your first query (with out view and the join venders. So now you need an ON clause that works. as you can't use derived columns you have to repeat the LEFT Statement again as one part pf the comparison  et voila you got your query